# Handling exceptions Python Selenium firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I get an error code when executing a php script, I understand why this error exist and it is correct, the thing is I dont want to try and correct it I just want to quit the driver when I get this exception.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button id="button-dialog-send" class="btn btn-orange btn-orange--small"> could not be scrolled into view
```

what is the simplest way to call a "driver.quit()" if "ElementNotInteractableException" is found.

Thank you.

I think I got it

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#top > span").click()
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#send > span").click()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "button-dialog-send").click()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0)")
except ElementNotInteractableException:
     pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Try except blocks

```
try:
  print(x)
except ElementNotInteractableException:
  print("An exception occurred")
```